# Internal Server Error while retrieving data from code Behind using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have a C# Code and I want to retrieve a value from code into Javascript.
But getting **Internal Server Error** in Browser.

Below is my C# and Javascript Code.

```
protected string Getdata()
        {
            
            string Name = "Pradeep";
            return Name;
}
```

Below is the JavaScript

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#Btn_Show').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Bootstrap_Chart.aspx/Getdata",
                        data: "{}",
                        dataType: "Json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (res) {
                            //var values = res.Name;
                            alert(res.Name);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert('Error: '+error);
                        }

                    })
                })
            })

            </script>
```

While executing the Application getting following output:
[image]

Comment: change `data: "{}"` to `data: {}`. you can use browser console to see the actual request, response, error. I think I got the issue. It is assuming the GET method but you are calling the POST method. so declare the method in C# with `HTTPPOST `

Comment: Changed data: "{}" to data: {}, same error occurring. This is Asp.Net C# code, kindly suggest how to get [HttpPost].